# Why does the Rambam change the wording of the Mishna in Succah 20b?

Tags: rambam, masechet-sukkah

The Mishna in the beginning of the second Perek of Succah writes הישן תחת המטה בסוכה - לא יצא ידי חובתו

When the Rambam codifies this Halacha in the Mishna Torah, he changes the word הישן to היושב. He writes (5:23) מטה שבתוך הסוכה אם גבוהה עשרה טפחים **היושב תחתיה** לא יצא ידי חובתו מפני שהיא סוכה בתוך סוכה

Why does the Rambam change the wording?